# eCopy ShareScan

Tags: scanning, ecopy

Anyone has any experience on [eCopy ShareScan](http://www.ecopy.com/products-ecopy-sharescan.asp) and the [SDK](http://www.ecopy.com/products-software-development-kit--sdk-.asp) behind it? From what I know it's a sdk that provides a uniform interface that connects your application to the backend scanner.

My question is, apart from the cost concern, is there anything it is superior as compared to any other components that support [TWAIN](http://www.twain.org/) ( such as [VintaSoft](http://www.vintasoft.com/))?

**Note: This is a question also asked on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/9848/ecopy-sharescan).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pre answer my own question, so that if there is no correct answer, I can select this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The proprietary eCopy ShareScan SDK knows its equipment better than any third-party which would be writing software to support it.  The proprietary SDK would most likely be able to take advantage of all of the features of its equipment.

However, a generic or third-party SDK might be easier to learn, since it would be written by a team which develops other SDKs too.

You may be able to find an free, open-source TWAIN library that would work.