# eCopy ShareScan

Tags: scanning, ecopy

Anyone has any experience on [eCopy ShareScan](http://www.ecopy.com/products-ecopy-sharescan.asp) and the [SDK](http://www.ecopy.com/products-software-development-kit--sdk-.asp) behind it? From what I know it's a sdk that provides a uniform interface that connects your application to the backend scanner.

My question is, apart from the cost concern, is there anything it is superior as compared to any other components that support [TWAIN](http://www.twain.org/) ( such as [VintaSoft](http://www.vintasoft.com))?

**Note: Moderators! Do move this topic to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if you really believe that it should belong there.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [eCopy ShareScan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162578/ecopy-sharescan)

Answer (score 1):

eCopy ShareScan and the SDK behind is more than just a toolkit to support Twain. It does support TWAIN and ISIS interfaces in a kiosk environment for a scanner or MFP, however the more significant value is for smart devices that have an application platform.

Some expamples of these platforms are Canon's MEAP interface, Ricoh's ESA platform, Konica Minlota's Integrated platform or Xerox EIP to name a few.  The eCopy ShareScan SDK enables the development of a single application with form factors to support each of these platforms with a single integration or connector. This means a developer can write their integration once and support each of these device interfaces with a single offering.

For more infotmation http://www.ecopy.com/partners-software-alliance-programs.asp